# Connecting to database with flex

Tags: database, apache-flex, connection

I am writing a large flex app that has to connect to a database many times. I currently am using asp pages to connect, but I would like to use the most efficient option. What do you think is the best way to connect to a database from a flex app?

Thanks for answering!

Comment: Your question is too vague to provide a meaningful answer. Nevertheless you could have a look at this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328097/which-is-the-best-way-to-get-data-in-my-flex-application/8328424#8328424) where I've discussed some options for remoting.

Comment: Flex after compiling to SWF can only communicate to a database through web services (WSDL, REST, etc.).

You can create a web service that performs some CRUD operations on a database and have your Flex application call that web service.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your project limitations. In most cases Flex projects connect to existing databases and there are some server-side technologies already adopted in the company. If you share your limitations we would be able to give you more realistic advice.

Imagining you don't have any limitations I can recommend you using [GraniteDS](http://graniteds.org). I've never used it myself but folks say it's great.