# Flex with Java VS Coldfusion VS PHP

Tags: java, php, apache-flex, coldfusion

I'm starting/learning to build Flex application with Flash Builder 4.5. The tutorial link me to http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/testdrive/articles/1_build_a_flex_app.html and I notice that you can use Flex with Java, Coldfusion or PHP. I'm wondering what are the differences between each of them and which one should I choose?

Thanks

Comment: What sort of hosting/budget are you working with? Do you want to use shared hosting, VPSs or dedicated servers? Look into what each of these will cost to deploy for the size of your app. Additionally I'd expect there are licensing costs for deploying Coldfusion, whereas the other two are free to use.

Comment: (Btw, although it is interesting, in general this kind of question is too discursive for here).

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough, but I'm just starting out on flex and really have no idea about it. Thanks for all the comment

Comment: Don't worry about it - just add the necessary clarifications to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a very similar question with my answer here: [Which is the best way to get Data in my Flex Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328097/which-is-the-best-way-to-get-data-in-my-flex-application/8328424#8328424).

However this question deals more with the performance aspect so I'll elaborate. Basically you should just pick whichever language you're most efficient with. Note that besides Java, ColdFusion and PHP, that could also be Ruby, Python, .NET and probably more, as long as it has an implementation of AMF (de)serialization.

If there's one of these languages you know best, pick that. If not, go for ColdFusion or Java since I believe they're the easiest to setup for communication with Flex. And for the choice between those two:

- Java is a strongly typed language and is very similar to ActionScript 3, which you'll be using on the client side. On the [BlazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS) site you'll find a Tomcat server with BlazeDS integrated and some example applications with Flex and Java.
- ColdFusion is loosely typed and a productivity layer built on top of Java. It comes prepackaged with BlazeDS and is very easy to set up with Flex. However, compared to Tomcat it's fairly heavy on resources, which you might want to take into consideration if you plan to run it locally.

Comment: +1 for noting that the choice isn't limited to just the three langs mentioned in the question.

Comment: @halfer You're correct about the licensing: CF can cost between 500 en 800$. Not the development server though: that's free too.

Comment: Oops, that's one 0 short on those figures. Should be 5000-8000

Comment: Yikes. I'd want the application server to regularly make me a good cup of tea for that kind of cash!

Comment: @halfer Seems I was a bit misinformed, so here are the reals numbers: it's 650$ for the standard edition and 3750$ for enterprise.

Comment: There are also open source alternatives to Adobe ColdFusion (ACF). Look into Railo and OpenBD if your budget is tight.

Comment: @AaronGreenlee Do these come with BlazeDS or another means of doing Flex remoting?

Answer (score 0):

Flex with Java is my choice because Java is strongly typed, has a good API, lot of thirdparty libraries and it is good in dealing with XML.

Comment: Whereas PHP is loosely typed, has a good API, a lot of thirdparty libraries and is good in dealing with XML `;-)`.